# Using django cut filter in template with regexp

Tags: django, django-templates

I have URLs that all end with an image filename. I am trying to strip all of the URL except the filename, however the URL path can vary, as I have images in different directories.

I am wondering if there is someway to use regexp with the cut filter, as I have not found a way to do so yet.

An example of what I am trying to do:

```
{{ instance.image_url|cut:"/images/products/*/dl_img/" }}'
```

Where `*` refers to various directory names, such as `beds` or `tables`

Is there an easy way to do this in a template?

Comment: You should consider creating your own [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). Just take the example (ironically it's `cut`) and change it to work with a regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your own [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
# templatetags/cut_re.py
import re 

from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def cut_re(value, search): 
    return re.sub(search, "", value)
```

And then use it like

```
{% load cut_re %}
{{ instance.image_url|cut_re:"/images/products/.*/dl_img/" }}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Was wondering if there was any built in way, but this works fine :)

Comment: Actually, this isn't working at all, and I can't see why. I'm not getting any errors at all, but the filter just has no effect and the entire url is returned. I'm using it within quotes although I don't think that should make a difference? : `id="{{ instance.image_url|cut_re:'/images/products/.*/dl_img/' }}" `

Comment: Did you verify if the regex works? Or test it with a simpler regex, like just removing a letter or something?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working even without regexp, for example `id="{{ instance.image_url|cut_re:'/images/ }}"` returns nothing.

Comment: You could try do debug it like: `python manage.py shell`... `In [1]: from common.templatetags.cut_re import cut_re

In [2]: cut_re("test", "t")
Out[2]: 'es'`

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work in the shell fine: https://imgur.com/a/3CARaei - I wonder why it isn't working in the template, it seems to register and be loaded fine

Comment: Ah, the error was somewhere else, it works perfectly :)